# Changing layouts without restarting LyX?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I'm using LyX to layout a booklet of speeches from a conference based on the Editorium LyxBook layout.  I've been modifying a lot to meet our needs, and when I started on that a few weeks ago, I found a command that would reload LyX and get it to re-read the layout file without closing LyX, restarting, needing to re-open files, etc.  I even assigned a keyboard shortcut to it.

So my workflow was:

1. Make a change to LyXBook.layout in an external editor, save file.
2. Ctrl-Shift-some_key to magically get LyX to reread the layout file
3. Ctrl-R to update PDF preview
4. Repeat...

I've looked through the preferences keyboard shortcuts pane, and I can't find the shortcut I assigned.  And, unfortunately, it isn't just to Tools -> Reconfigure, because when I do that, I still need to manually restart for my changes in the .layout file to be recognized.

e.g. changes like: `\setlength\afterchapskip{2\baselineskip}` to `\setlength\afterchapskip{0\baselineskip}`

I think it goes without saying that it is a major nuisance to have to totally restart LyX to see every minor change!

Answer (score 4):

Well, OK, I found my answer, digging through browser history.

There is a command `layout-reload`

Tools -> Preferences

then

Editing -> Shortcuts

then it is under "Font, Layout and Text-Classes" and you can assign a keyboard shortcut to `layout-reload` as I did.

[image: Preferences dialog showing the layout-reload command]

Comment: I'd add that local layouts might be better for quick testing of things: Document > Settings > Local layout.

Comment: I agree with @PhilipPirrip -- I just spent hours tweaking a layout for the exam class and much of my development was done in Local layout. The "validate" button is just so helpful! Use it often. However, take care not to click on another document tab (if you have more than one open in LyX) before "applying" the validated changes to your the first document. Your Local Layout buffer will be replace by the other document's, and you'll lose any changes.